# make pattern to automatically generate dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to allow pattern rules to generate the correct header dependencies for me. I've attempted do this by, but it's failing

For example, if I have files `foo.cpp`, `foo.h`, `bar.cpp`, `bar.h` and `foo.h` includes `bar.h`. with Makefile:

```
foo_H=foo.h $(bar_H)
bar_H=bar.h

%.o: %.cpp $(%_H)
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

but make will not update when `foo.h` or `bar.h` is changed.

why does this fail and how can it be fixed?

Comment: If you are using a decently modern compiler (GCC or Clang for example) you can follow the steps described here for automatically-generated dependency tracking: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that you can use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion) for it:

```
foo_H = foo.h $(bar_H)
bar_H = bar.h

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: %.cpp $$($$*_H)
        $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way gnu make works.

1. the variable `bar_H` is undefined when assigning `foo_H`. So `foo_H` will just have the value `foo.h`.
2. the pattern expansion will not work inside `$(...)`. It just will look up the variable `%_H` which does not exists, i.e. is empty.
3. `%<` and `%@` is wrong. You probably intended to write `$<` and `$@`.
4. You makefile needs at least one non target. A patterned rule is not sufficient.
5. A patterned rule will not be used unless all dependencies exist. This might not be intended here.
6. Your patterned rule will not apply because it searches for a `foo.c` rather than `foo.cpp`.

---

The intended behavior is achieved by

```
foo.o : foo.h bar.h
bar.o : bar.h

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Note that the dependencies are specified separately from the executable commands.

---

Another note: if you want to get rid of the include dependency hell you might want to have a look at *cmake*.

Comment: I'm fairly certain point 1 is only true if you use `:=`, and with `=` it is evaluated when used. Point 3 is a typo in my, example, with what i actually have written it was correct. Point 4 was omitted in my example, but present. Point 5 all dependencies do exist. Point 6 again a typo on my part.

Comment: Point 2 is probably correct, but I would appreciate an alternative syntax that would achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

`$(%_H)` could not expand because as stated in

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

`Note that expansion using ‘%’ in pattern rules occurs after any variable or function expansions, which take place when the makefile is read`

so it seems like using patterns to achieve this kind of logic is a dead end

As an alternative, I used `foreach` and `include` as follows:

makedep.mk

```
$(CUR_OBJ): $(CUR_OBJ:.o=.cpp) $($(CUR_OBJ:.o=_H))
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Makefile

```
foo_H=foo.h $(bar_H)
bar_H=bar.h

SRCS=foo.cpp bar.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)


$(foreach obj,$(OBJS),$(eval CUR_OBJ:=$(obj)) $(eval include makedep.mk))
```

since there are only make variables and no pattern matching `%` everything can expand properly